# Issue with various screen resolutions in Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout

The user interface of my application works fine in normal screens(470dp*320dp) but in case of small screens(426dp*320dp) various issues are popping up.
I have added ***supports-screens*** tag to the Manifest file, made separate layout directory(**layout, layout-normal, layout-small**) for the various screen resolutions, but the problem still persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really need to add details -- the actual "various issues" and what you've tried (in code) so far to resolve them.

Comment: What kind of issues are popping up? Can you add some screen shots?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different layout files for different resolutions with same name like `layout-ldpi`, `layout-mdpi`, `layout-hdpi`, `layout-xhdpi`, `layout-xxhdpi` and design according to the resolution. Android OS makes the choice of selecting the res file from respective folder.

Hope it helps